# Getting db string in textview

Tags: android, database, textview

I read out data from a database into a String. Now i want to put this String into a textview to show my data in list. I execute the read method and want to show the return string mit the data. Problem is: Android studio cannot resolve the "symbol" aka dbString.

Databasetostring:

```
public String databaseToString(){
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    //Every Column and row
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TODO + " WHERE 1";

    //Cursor points to a location in your results
    //First row point here, second row point here

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    while(!c.isAfterLast()){
        //Extracts first name and adds to string
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("firstName"))!=null){
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("firstName"));
            c.moveToNext();
        /*
         * Displaying all other columns
         */
        }
    }
    db.close();
    return dbString;
```

MainActivity:

```
Button refresh_list;
ToDoDB showDb;
TextView datalist;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    datalist = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showallData);
    refresh_list = (Button)findViewById(R.id. refresh_list);
    refresh_list.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    datalist.setText(dbString);
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: Your onCreate doesn't show anywhere where it retrieves the dbstring

Comment: Isn't it should be datalist.setText(databaseToString()); ?

Comment: you are on a completely wrong way. If I see this correct, You have a database class and the activity. But to call the method `databaseTostring()` you have to make a reference to the database class inside your activity. Or, second case, this method is inside your activity, then you have to make a global String `dbString`